# laravel services.json not created

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Sometimes my `services.json` is missing after running `composer update` or `php artisan clear-compiled`.

I checked the permissions and even changed it to 777 on the storage folder but it does not help. How can I debug whats wrong?

There are no entries in my laravel log and nothing in my apache log. I'm using "laravel/framework": "4.1.*"

Comment: Is the `meta` folder still in the storage directory when you have this problem? Laravel will error with an inability to write to `services.json` if this folder is missing. Also `chmod 777 app/storage -R` will recursively change permissions for all folders in storage rather than just the storage dir itself.

Comment: jep, meta folder still there. I noticed, that running "artisan optimize" removes it. After running "artisan migrate:refresh" the file exists again.

Comment: @nonsenz please mark the answer as accepted if worked to you :)

Answer (score 19):

Just run a `php artisan serve` and stop, this will create the services.json file.

Comment: I need `services.json` in order to run `php artisan serve`. At least that's the conclusion I've arrived at. When I run `php artisan serve` I see the same message. EDIT: I don't understand this at all because after manually creating `services.json` and adding an object in `"providers"` then accidentally going up a to the wrong command from earlier that deleted `services.json` and running `php artisan serve` again everything is perfectly fine. Nothing is making sense right now. 

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your web server has access to the files/folders specifically app/storage/meta/services.json if this file/folder is not there create it and add some json to see if you can accesss it in the browser.
If forbidden/denied see permissions below:

Check you have these folders

```
app/storage/views
app/storage/logs
app/storage/sessions
```

Set everything to be read/write

```
chmod -R 777 /app/storage
```

Create services.json and add the following

```
    {
        "providers": []
    }
```

After creating the above try loading the project or php artisan serve