# file_put_contents(.../bootstrap/cache/services.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I kept getting this error when running any `php artisan` commands.

> [ErrorException]
>     file_put_contents(/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/bheng/md-bheng/bootstrap/cache/services.json): failed to open stream: No suc
>     h file or directory

[image]

**How do I stop that ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit** - If the `services.json` file does not exist, run `php artisan serve` and then stop to forcibly create the file.
See: [laravel services.json not created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23336579/laravel-services-json-not-created)

**Edit** - updated answer to explain each command.

First, ignore the `$` at the beginning of each command. These are to indicate that the commands are executed in Terminal.

To find your username, if you don't already know it, run:

```
$ whoami
```

For me, this would output `rob`.

Next we want to **ch**ange the **own**ership (`chown`) of the `services.json` file. We set the owner to your username (in my case `rob`) and the group to `_www`, which is the user MAMP runs as.

```
$ sudo chown rob:_www /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/bheng/md-bheng/bootstrap/cache/services.json
```

Next we want to **ch**ange the **own**ership (`chown`) of the `storage` directory. We again set the owner to your username (in my case `rob`) and the group to `_www`. You may also notice the `-R` option. This will execute this command recursively through all of the subdirectories contained within the `storage` directory.

```
$ sudo chown -R rob:_www /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/bheng/md-bheng/storage
```

Finally, we want to change the permissions for individual files and directories within the storage directory. The following commands will `find` within the `storage` directory, all directories (`-type d`) or all files (`-type f`) and execute the command following `-exec`.

```
$ sudo find /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/bheng/md-bheng/storage -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
$ sudo find /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/bheng/md-bheng/storage -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

The commands we're executing will **ch**ange **mod**e (`chmod`) for each directory or file. [Read this to learn more about permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod). I've linked to Wikipedia, because it's explains things quite simply. There are likely better resources out there.

Essentially however, `775` will grant read, write and execute permissions on the directories. `664` will grant read and write permissions on the files.

Comment: Can you please explain a little of what each line do ?

Comment: Why 775 or 664 ? How do you know that ?

Comment: @ihue I've updated my response with an explanation of each line as requested.

Answer (score 3):

```
[ErrorException]
file_put_contents(/var/www/project/bootstrap/cache/services.php): 
failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

For me, it was because of `bootstrap/cache` folder.
I deleted the `cache` forcefully, hence I hit this error.

Just create back the `cache` folder, it would work fine.

`$>cd projectDir/bootstrap`

`$>projectDir/bootstrap`> mkdir cache

would work

Answer (score 1):

if the folder bootstrap/cache DOES exist or has previously existed or you have deleted / .gitignored it :

```
composer install
```

or

```
composer.phar install
```

should fix this right up. (which one you use depends on your composer setup. For me its the second option)

This error can happen if you have run composer update for the first time in a while.

Answer (score 0):

i used to have this problem
all you should to do is create a folder named "cache" inside the folder "bootstrap" of the project , then a file named "services.php" , after enter the command composer install and everything should just work so fine .